# Reconstructing serialized objects

Tags: java, deserialization

Im trying to reconstruct a serialized object and access data from it.

This is how Im sending the object.

```
    Socket socket = new Socket ("localhost", port);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
    Tester t = new Tester("test");
    out.writeObject(t);
    out.flush();
```

And this is how I'm receiving it

// This is how the server is being built

```
    private ServerSocket server;
    server = new ServerSocket(port);
    newsocket = server.accept();
```

// And this is how Im actually getting the object

```
    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(newSocket.getInputStream());
    Tester obj = (Tester) input.readObject();
    System.out.println(obj.getText());
```

However I only get the following output

```
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@237360be
```

What I was hoping to get was the string I sent in the object "Test". Is there anything Im doing wrong?

---

My Tester class looks like this

```
public class Tester implements Serializable {
    private String theMessage = "";

    public Tester(String message) {
        theMessage = message;
    }

    public String getText() {
         return theMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown looks fine.  You are trying to print a stack trace as an array which is unusual to say the least.

Comment: Can we see your code for `getText()` method?

Comment: Show us, how you are constructing `newSocket` object?

Comment: Maybe you have different versions of the class on the client and server? I would expect to see an actual exception, though, not a serialized stack trace. You might try dropping the serialization, and see if you can send/receive a simple string with readers and writers, to see if it's a socket problem or a serialization problem.

Comment: Can not reproduce your error. Your code works fine, output is really 'test'.

Comment: Have you wrapped your socket listener code into some try...catch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you had wrapped code-block of socket listener into `try...catch` statement, where you are using some logger in `catch` part in an incorrect way: it prints the stacktrace instead of printing the error cause. This is the most probable explanation, why you receive `[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;...`.

Indeed your socket-listener code catches some `Exception`, which you have to print in an appropriate way.

Comment: @russoue, I agree, but this is a most probable explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream();
Tester tester0 = new Tester("test")
oos.writeObject(tester0);
oos.close();
System.out.println(tester0.getText());

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
Tester tester = (Tester) ois.readObject();
System.out.println(tester.getText());
```

If this doesn't work, you may have a bug in your serialization code.

Comment: Hi Peter, I get the error on the reciving end (cannot find symbol baos) do I need to set this somewhere?

Comment: you need to run the code in one method/test. It's defined at the start.